# how to clear the fields when one page to another page come back in angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms, ionic-framework

we have more than one page each page have forms. in Page 1 When i entered some data in one form and click on submit and navigate to another page 2, in that page2  i entered data to some fields and i navigating back to page 1 and i click on submit in page 1 and navigating to page 2 in that time the fields are not cleared. i need to clear the form fields using angularjs any one please help.

We are facing issue like below

[image]

We need like this below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the **cache-view**, you can disable the cache with `cache-view="false"` or you can clean the fields manually using the enter event `$ionicView.enter`. 
Is up to you where to disable the cache, eg.

```
Disable cache within state provider

$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})

Disable cache with an attribute

<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

If you want to clean the fields manually, you will have to do something like this in your **controller**:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $scope.field1 = '';
    $scope.field2 = '';
    $scope.field3 = '';
});
```

Comment: it can be on state provider or directly on the <ion-view tag. I added an example.